# I want to call hello() function in every methods FunctionItem() in python. But my code should run in windows cmd not in python shell. Help me out

Tags: python-3.x

I want to call the hello() function in every method `FunctionItem()` in python. But my code should run in windows cmd not in python shell.
Here is the code I have so far,any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import sys
import os
import fire

from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.format import *
from consolemenu.items import *

def hello():
    print("Hello World")

def main():

    menu_format = MenuFormatBuilder().set_border_style_type(MenuBorderStyleType.HEAVY_BORDER) \
        .set_prompt("SELECT>") \
        .set_title_align('center') \
        .set_subtitle_align('center') \
        .set_left_margin(4) \
        .set_right_margin(4) \
        .show_header_bottom_border(True)

    menu = ConsoleMenu("Root Menu", "This is the Root Menu Subtitle", formatter=menu_format)
    submenu = SelectionMenu(["Timestamp", "Command Addressing", "Address", "Size"], title="Trace Validation",
                        subtitle="These menu items return to the previous menu",
                        formatter=menu_format)
    submenu_item = SubmenuItem("Trace Validation", submenu=submenu)
    submenu_item.set_menu(menu)



    function_item = FunctionItem("Basic Trace Analysis scripts", hello)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. to just run this from cmd, you need python installed, remove the "def main()" and add a "menu.start()" at the end. Then call "python script_file.py" to execute your script

Comment: basic things i did. only thing is hello() is not read by FunctionItem() when it is called inside FunctionItem()

Comment: FunctionItem("abc", hello) getting executed in python shell but not in command prompt

Comment: how does your script look like when you call it from cmd ?

Comment: it is getting called but i think you couldn't see, as it is return to menu as soon as it called, to confirm add time.sleep(1) for second in hello() after print you would see it is called ?

Comment: That is exactly what my answer down below pertains to, he's simply not seeing it because it is being instantly cleared out by CMD, so yes, if you spam the second option(or use time, haven't tried for verifi) you can clearly see that hello world was called and printed. You could just write a file to prove it working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally mis-read the question I apologize. For me, this code works perfectly as expected after appending the items to the menu and then showing the menu, I did remove the fire import, it wasn't being used:

```
import sys
import os


from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.format import *
from consolemenu.items import *

def hello():
    print("Hello World")

def main():

    menu_format = MenuFormatBuilder().set_border_style_type(MenuBorderStyleType.HEAVY_BORDER) \
        .set_prompt("SELECT>") \
        .set_title_align('center') \
        .set_subtitle_align('center') \
        .set_left_margin(4) \
        .set_right_margin(4) \
        .show_header_bottom_border(True)

    menu = ConsoleMenu("Root Menu", "This is the Root Menu Subtitle", formatter=menu_format)
    submenu = SelectionMenu(["Timestamp", "Command Addressing", "Address", "Size"], title="Trace Validation",
                        subtitle="These menu items return to the previous menu",
                        formatter=menu_format)
    submenu_item = SubmenuItem("Trace Validation", submenu=submenu)
    submenu_item.set_menu(menu)



    function_item = FunctionItem("Call a python function", hello)
    menu.append_item(submenu_item)
    menu.append_item(function_item)
    menu.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

console-menu docs:
https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/

functionItem method:
https://console-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consolemenu/items/FunctionItem.html

*EDIT* I should notate that it will print way high on the terminal(linux) above the menu, but the function does run.

*EDIT* Second edit, last time I stack and work :) in cmd (windows) you have to really REALLY pay attention because the function will print hello world but cmd will clear it out to keep the menu looking good. SO, the function *does* run, just be quick to see it print or spam number 2 on the menu before the cmd clears it back out to keep the menu looking good. :)